# How to remove duplicate value between 2 array, Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to remove duplicated value between 2 arrays. How can I do?

[image]

- 1, 3, 4, 6 are duplicated in a both arrays, I want to unique values.

---

I using map() to show arrays of item_id contains of quantity but it's duplicate value, I don't want it.

```
$deliveries =  $pickupsGroupByDepartment->first()->map(function ($q) {
    return $q->deliveries->groupBy('delivery_date')->map(function($r) {
        return $r->mapToGroups(function ($item) {
              return [$item['item_id'] => $item['quantity']];
         });
     });
});
```

Comment: In the attached image which are the duplicated entries/values?

Comment: @KennyHorna 1, 3, 4, 6 are duplicated values of both arrays.

Comment: I think you could take advantage of the Collections class to filter this data.. the thing is.. what is your logic to group this items.. add what you need/want in the description (it'd be better if you provide an example) so we can help you solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_unique` function then combine it using `array_merge` function.

```
$array = array_unique (array_merge ($array1, $array2));
```

if your data is came from object in Laravel. you can use code below.

```
$result = $object1->merge($object2)->unique();
```

If the situation is dynamic data you can do this..

```
$results = [];

foreach($dynamicArray  as $key => $array){

    $results = array_unique (array_merge ($results, $array));

}
return $results;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's dynamic data. Sometimes it hasn't just 2 arrays or objects. How can I do this?

Comment: Just store it in one variable then merge another array into the variable you created,